# User model and User auth (Django and mysql)

Tags: mysql, django

I am new to py web dev. I am using django and mysql for my web app. My app works but i am not able to maintain the login session. after each query on main page it redirect me to login page. The reason for that is im not using the django User auth system instead i wrote my own auth code inside

````
```view.py ``` 
def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Studentlogin(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            try:
                currstudent = students.objects.get(email=email, password=password)
                expense = sublist.objects.all()
                return render (request, 'subscrap/main.html', {'student': currstudent, 'sublist': expense })
    

            except:
                messages.success(request, 'Error, either Email or Password is not correct')
                pass
    else:
        form = Studentlogin()
    return render(request, 'subscrap/login.html', {'form': form})
````

the login data is only accessible inside the login function and I have to call it every time to render and see an updated main.html. I searched on the web and the clue I got was that it might be because my user model aka(class students) is not actually built like a user model.  I am a newbie to the py syntax and web dev on it and confused about how to implement Django user auth and save my info in the Mysql database since most of the tutorials online use SQLite. Any help or clue would help me a lot. Thank you

```
class students(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 50 , null = True)
    passwordrepeat = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "students"
```

Comment: You're storing passwords unencrypted in plaintext? This is a really bad idea, you're putting your users at risk. Why are you not using the built-in auth system?

Comment: Plaintext, yup i know its is not the right way. I was making it work until i learn more about it. I am not using built in auth because i dont know how to do it with mysql. Most of the tutorials are working with SQLite

Comment: The database used does not make any difference at all, the built-in auth will work with any of them. Rolling your own auth is almost always a bad idea

Comment: Am i suppose to use Abstractbaseuser ? instead of models.Model. Since i have my own custom model or import User and use that.

Comment: Your model does not have any fields that the built-in User model doesn't have, use the built-in one

Comment: Hello @zayant21 you can follow official doc. to connect MySQL database in Django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/databases/#mysql-notes or you can see this blog post to work with MySQL in Django https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-django-app-and-connect-it-to-a-database

Comment: to create custom user model in Django follow this doc. https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Comment: @chickitychinachinesechicken acutally yes i got the answer ty for respoding me though i really appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

You should not be storing your passwords in plaintext, just use Django's built in authentication.  Django's ORM manages different databases so that you don't have to.  For the most part, moving from SQLite to MySQL will have no effect on the application because of the ORM.  MySQL specific documentation is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/databases/#mysql-notes).

If your goal is to log a user/student in, then just extend the user model as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).  Your student model will then have all of the attributes you need and more like `is_staff`, `is_superuser` or `last_login`.